# A helper method to create a dictionary of a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have an application where I have a number of classes that I have derived from XML Files (the Property Names in the class match the node names in the XML), and I can populate this class using reflection (some code I found on stackoverflow that I adapted).  Essentially, I enumerate all the child nodes of a XML node, and try to get and set the corresponding property name in my class.  This works well enough.  While I understand that XML Serialization might be a better solution to this, I am OK with what I've got.  My question is what I do with the populated classes.

Reading the XML, I would (say) get 200 nodes that convert to 200 instances of a given class.  I want to store these in a dictionary.  I would then have another XML to (say) generate 100 instances of a different class, and I want those stored in a different dictionary.

The code I use to parse the XML is as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, Book> oBookCollection = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
XML_File_Reader oDoc = new XML_File_Reader(@"C:\apps\bookList.xml");
if (oDoc.IsDocumentValid)
{
    XmlNodeList oList = oDoc.GetList("Row");
    if (oList.Count !=0)
    foreach (XmlNode xn in oList)
    {

        XmlNode oThisNode = xn;
        Book oThisBook = new Book(oMyLibrary, oThisNode);

        oDoc.MigrateXMLtoObject(oBuilding, oThisNode);
        oBookCollection .Add(oBook.BookName, oBook);

    }

}
oDoc = null;
```

As you can see, this has specific references to a specific class type.  I want to be able to use a generic method that can just as easily populate the XML for DVDs and Toys as for Books.

For info, the existing "MigrateXMLtoObject" routine is as follows:

```
public void MigrateXMLtoObject(object myObject, XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
        IEnumerator list = node.GetEnumerator();
        XmlNode tempNode;

        while (list.MoveNext())
        {
            tempNode = (XmlNode)list.Current;

            propertyInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(tempNode.Name);


            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    DateTime val = DateTime.MinValue;
                    DateTime.TryParse(tempNode.InnerText, out val);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, val, null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                {
                    int val = 0;
                    Int32.TryParse(tempNode.InnerText, out val);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, val, null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    bool val = false;
                    Boolean.TryParse(tempNode.InnerText, out val);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, val, null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    string val = "";
                    val = tempNode.InnerText;
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, val, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, tempNode.Value, null);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The things I've considered are making the Books, DVDs etc inherit from a common base class, but don't think that will work, because if I pass the BaseClass to the method, when it tries to use reflection to match the properties, they will be the properties of the baseclass not the derived class.

I then did some searching here, and saw mention of using Generics.  Unfortunately, while I use dictionary<> and list<> objects, I've never written my own Generic, and so don't know how to use them (nor whether this is actually the solution I'm looking for!)

I did write this, and clearly it won't work / won't compile, but it might be a useful fragment for people to push me in the right direction:

```
public Dictionary<string, T> MigrateXMLtoObject<T>(string xmlPath, MyLibrary oLibrary)
    {
        Dictionary<string, T> oDictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        XML_File_Reader oDoc = new XML_File_Reader(xmlPath);
        if (oDoc.IsDocumentValid)
        {
            XmlNodeList oList = oDoc.GetList("Row");
            if (oList.Count != 0)
                foreach (XmlNode xn in oList)
                {

                    XmlNode oThisNode = xn;
                    //T othisItem = new T(oLibrary, oThisNode);

                    oDoc.MigrateXMLtoObject(T, oThisNode);
                    oDictionary.Add(T.Type, T);

                }

        }
        oDoc = null;

        return oDictionary;
    }
```

Do I need some sort of 'switch' to evaluate T, and create the corresponding base class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it's hard to know exactly what would work best for you. But naively, here's what I'd suggest:

```
public Dictionary<string, T> MigrateXMLtoObject<T>(
    string xmlPath, MyLibrary oLibrary, Func<MyLibrary, XmlNode, T> factory)
{
    Dictionary<string, T> oDictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    XML_File_Reader oDoc = new XML_File_Reader(xmlPath);
    if (oDoc.IsDocumentValid)
    {
        XmlNodeList oList = oDoc.GetList("Row");
        if (oList.Count != 0)
            foreach (XmlNode xn in oList)
            {

                XmlNode oThisNode = xn;
                T thisItem = factory(oLibrary, oThisNode);

                // It's not really clear to me what you wanted to do
                // here. If the object constructor is handling applying
                // the node data to the object, you shouldn't need to
                // "migrate" more, right? And the dictionary seems to
                // want to add the object as the value, with the key
                // being some text. Where do you get the key?
                //oDoc.MigrateXMLtoObject(T, oThisNode);
                oDictionary.Add(objectKey, thisItem);

            }

    }
    oDoc = null;

    return oDictionary;
}
```

Where you call it something like this:

```
MigrateXMLtoObject(xmlPath, library, (l, n) => new Book(l, n));
```

Note that if you are only passing the `MyLibrary` object for the purpose of passing to the constructor of the object, then in this approach you don't need that as a method parameter. Instead, you can build it into the factory delegate. E.g.:

```
MigrateXMLtoObject(xmlPath, node => new Book(library, n));
```

I'd also suggest you get rid of all those "o"'s prefixing your variable names. It's not helping. :)

Comment: Thank-you.  I'll have a play with this and see where it gets me (I haven't used Function Delegates before, so this is a great learning experience!)  The Key is actually a node element that is (fortunately) unique.  In the Book & DVD classes, it is called "Type", which is a stupid name.... I will grab it from the XML Node rather than try to get it from the newly-created class.  On the migration issue, the object constructor just gets passed the MyLibrary, effectively as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

> The things I've considered are making the Books, DVDs etc inherit from
>   a common base class, but don't think that will work, because if I pass
>   the BaseClass to the method, when it tries to use reflection to match
>   the properties, they will be the properties of the baseclass not the
>   derived class.

sorry but, you think wrong :( ..

```
public void SayMyType(BaseClass obj)
{
      Console.Write(obj.GetType())//will output the type of object 'DerivedClass' not the parameter 'BaseClass '
}
SayMyType(new DerivedClass())
```

so inheritance IS the way to go..